# Reactor Netty HTTP client opens new connection in Pool mode

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, netty, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

Set up:
Java 17
Spring Cloud Gateway 4.0.7
Netty client propetrties

```
spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.connect-timeout=3000
spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.pool.type=fixed
spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.pool.acquire-timeout=3000
spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.pool.max-connections=150
spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.pool.max-idle-time=45s
```

The problem is that from time to time, Netty HTTP client, instead of reusing connections from the pool, starts opening and closing new ones. Sometimes tens of thousands at a time - looks like for every request. Thus overloading system.
Here is a sample TCP Dump.

```
19:40:35.301144 IP 10.15.6.191.44436 > 10.15.31.167.443: Flags [S], seq 3949612662, win 26883, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 3802670541 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:40:35.302165 IP 10.15.31.167.443 > 10.15.6.191.44436: Flags [S.], seq 38622828, ack 3949612663, win 26847, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 3342866260 ecr 3802670541,nop,wscale 8], length 0
19:40:35.302176 IP 10.15.6.191.44436 > 10.15.31.167.443: Flags [.], ack 1, win 211, options [nop,nop,TS val 3802670542 ecr 3342866260], length 0
19:40:35.306160 IP 10.15.6.191.44436 > 10.15.31.167.443: Flags [P.], seq 1:518, ack 1, win 211, options [nop,nop,TS val 3802670546 ecr 3342866260], length 517
19:40:35.307201 IP 10.15.31.167.443 > 10.15.6.191.44436: Flags [.], ack 518, win 110, options [nop,nop,TS val 3342866265 ecr 3802670546], length 0
19:40:35.308037 IP 10.15.31.167.443 > 10.15.6.191.44436: Flags [P.], seq 1:5444, ack 518, win 110, options [nop,nop,TS val 3342866266 ecr 3802670546], length 5443
19:40:35.308049 IP 10.15.6.191.44436 > 10.15.31.167.443: Flags [.], ack 5444, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 3802670548 ecr 3342866266], length 0
19:40:35.311636 IP 10.15.6.191.44436 > 10.15.31.167.443: Flags [P.], seq 518:644, ack 5444, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 3802670551 ecr 3342866266], length 126
19:40:35.312798 IP 10.15.31.167.443 > 10.15.6.191.44436: Flags [.], ack 644, win 110, options [nop,nop,TS val 3342866271 ecr 3802670551], length 0
19:40:35.312827 IP 10.15.31.167.443 > 10.15.6.191.44436: Flags [P.], seq 5444:5615, ack 644, win 110, options [nop,nop,TS val 3342866271 ecr 3802670551], length 171
19:40:35.312970 IP 10.15.6.191.44436 > 10.15.31.167.443: Flags [P.], seq 644:1306, ack 5615, win 435, options [nop,nop,TS val 3802670553 ecr 3342866271], length 662
19:40:35.315491 IP 10.15.31.167.443 > 10.15.6.191.44436: Flags [P.], seq 5615:5806, ack 1306, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 3342866274 ecr 3802670553], length 191
19:40:35.315543 IP 10.15.31.167.443 > 10.15.6.191.44436: Flags [P.], seq 5806:5840, ack 1306, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 3342866274 ecr 3802670553], length 34
19:40:35.315753 IP 10.15.6.191.44436 > 10.15.31.167.443: Flags [.], ack 5840, win 520, options [nop,nop,TS val 3802670556 ecr 3342866274], length 0
19:40:35.316294 IP 10.15.6.191.44436 > 10.15.31.167.443: Flags [P.], seq 1306:1337, ack 5840, win 520, options [nop,nop,TS val 3802670556 ecr 3342866274], length 31
19:40:35.316386 IP 10.15.6.191.44436 > 10.15.31.167.443: Flags [F.], seq 1337, ack 5840, win 520, options [nop,nop,TS val 3802670556 ecr 3342866274], length 0
19:40:35.317277 IP 10.15.31.167.443 > 10.15.6.191.44436: Flags [F.], seq 5840, ack 1337, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 3342866275 ecr 3802670556], length 0
19:40:35.317287 IP 10.15.6.191.44436 > 10.15.31.167.443: Flags [.], ack 5841, win 520, options [nop,nop,TS val 3802670557 ecr 3342866275], length 0
19:40:35.317362 IP 10.15.31.167.443 > 10.15.6.191.44436: Flags [.], ack 1338, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 3342866275 ecr 3802670556], length 0
```

Does anyone has an idea what's going on and why Netty doesn't use pool?